# How to redirect every raised error into popup?

Tags: python, exception, kivy

**GOAL:** having errors redirected to a unique Popup that will display the error on the kivy app instead of the terminal. It may prevent the application from crashing and show the user error message that he can give me to debug the application.

**GUESS:** Here is a mvp of how to do it but I don't know how to do it for most of the error without coding it every time.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text: "name"
'''

class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
       box = Builder.load_string(KV)
       try:
           int("za")
       except Exception as e:
           MyPopup(title=str(e), size_hint=(0.5, 0.5))
       return box

class MyPopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.open()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really. The only way to catch *all* exceptions would be to "try-except" the MyApp.run() method. This doesn't work for multiple reasons.

I actually faced the same problem while developing my App.
I simply solved it by dividing nearly all code into functions and "try-excepting" the ones that I knew could fail, like user-input, computer-vision stuff, etc. (Basically anything, that takes an input, that isn't hard-coded.)

Answer (score -1):

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
try:
#code
except Exception as e:
Popup(title= "Error Bro" , content = Label(text = str(e)) , size_hint = (.5,.5))